# flex box make items 100% width of itself

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following html structure which I'm trying to arrange with a flex-box approach, with a row flex-direction. This is more or less the idea

```
<!-- 100% viewport width -->
<body>

    <!-- This toolbar should have whatever width may remain from parent -->
    <div class="toolbar-1 width-remain">

        <!-- This toolbar should have whatever width may remain from parent -->
        <div class="tb1-item1 width-remain">Some content</div>

        <!-- This toolbar should have 100% of its content -->
        <div class="tb1-item2 width-content">
            <!-- This toolbar should have 100% of its content -->
            <div class="tb1-item2-inner1 width-content">Some content</div>
            <!-- This toolbar should have 100% of its content -->
            <div class="tb1-item2-inner2 width-content">Some content</div>
            <!-- This toolbar should have 100% of its content -->
            <div class="tb1-item2-inner3 width-content">Some content</div>
        </div>

        <!-- This toolbar should have 100% of its content -->
        <div class="tb1-item3 width-content">Some content</div>
    </div>

    <!-- This toolbar should have 100% of its content -->
    <div class="toolbar-2 width-content">
        <div class="tb2-item1 width-content">Some content</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I was hoping to have two toolbars where one may grow in width (the second one, and the first one may occupy whatever space is left). Also, inside the first toolbar I have some extra items which I'd like to be able to grow in width, and one item which may occupy whatever space is left).

In general the width set in the inner items as
`flex: 1 1 100%;` takes the 100% of its parent, and not of its width. Setting `flex: 1 1 auto;` makes the items to have an even width. Also tried putting 0 to the `flex-growth` and *flex-shrink* properties. I've tried setting `justify-content: stretch;` to the toolbar parent, and `justify-self: stretch` to the inner items that may grow based on its content but with no success.

does anyone know how I can achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's a misunderstanding on how to use the `flex` property with child elements within an element with `display:flex;`.

Essentially you need to tell `.toolbar-1` it's okay to grow, and `.toolbar-2` it's okay to shrink. To accomplish that you can certainly use the `flex` property like so:

```css
.toolbar-1 {
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* grow shrink basis */
}
.toolbar-2 {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

Alternatively you can just use the grow and shrink properties:

```css
.toolbar-1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.toolbar-2 {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

I threw together this example based on what I understand from the question: [Flexible Toolbars](https://codepen.io/TXChetG/pen/WNjVqmZ)